# Border issue with Google Chrome on an Android phone

Tags: android, css

I need to begin with saying that this problem only occurs if I run my website in Google chrome on an Android phone.

One or more of these CSS statements causes a white border and there is space between the column headings:

```
    CODE:'    .BorderDotted_1
    CODE:'    {
    CODE:'        border-style:        solid;
    CODE:'        border-width:        thin thin thin thin;
    CODE:'        border-spacing:      0px;
    CODE:'        border-collapse:   collapse;
    CODE:'        border-color:        #a9a9a9; /* #5A5A5A */
    CODE:'    }
```

I wanted to attach a document that shows screenshots of what this style looks like with 3 web browsers on both my cell phone and my computer, but that feature has been removed for some reason!  How are we supposed to show you the discrepencies??

Comment: This is what the report should look like:

Comment: Why can't I attach documentation any longer?